# Grails - communicating between controllers and views

Tags: grails, view, groovy, textbox, controller

I'm wondering how I can populate a text box in my view from a list in my controller, I have been searching for examples for awhile, but haven't really found anything. I'm uncertain on how to access the text field from the view exactly, where as in Java you could do something as simple as `jTextField.getText()`. I'm also wondering on how to grab the text in my text box as well.

Below I'll post some example code of what I'm doing.

**Controller:**

```
def loadFile = {
    def propFile = "c:/props.txt"
    def propMap = [:]
    def propList = []

    new File(propFile).eachLine { line ->
    def (key,value) = line.split(':').collect { it.trim() }
    propMap."$key" = "$value"

    if(propMap) {
    propList << propMap
    propMap = [:]
    }
}

}

def saveFile = {
    //get contents of text box
    //over-write props.txt with new information
}
```

**View:**

```
<g:textField name="properties"/>
<span class="menuButton"/><g:link action="loadFile" controller="myController">Load File</g:link>
<span class="menuButton"/><g:link action="saveFile" controller="myController">Save File</g:link>
```

So, my question seems relatively straight forward, how do I access the text box when I want to populate it and save the data from it?

.

.

.

**EDIT**

After checking out some of the examples submitted by you guys, I have one last question.

Why does the following code act different when clicking the `Load File` button?

```
<g:form controller="drive">
<g:textArea name="properties" value="${params.param1}" rows="50" cols="6"/>
<br/>
<g:submitButton name="loadFile" value="Load File"/>
<g:submitButton name="saveFile" value="Save File"/>
</g:form>
<span class="menuButton"/><g:link action="loadFile" controller="drive">Load File</g:link>
```

When clicking the `g:submitButton` dealing with `loadFile` it redirects me to the `list` gsp. However, when I click the `menuButton` it loads the textArea with the text from the file. The reason I ask is because with the second option, the button isn't located where I would like it to be.

Comment: "println params?.properties" in your controller on form post to see what value was posted for the field

Comment: @virtualeyes forgive me as I'm relatively new to the web-end of apps, but I don't see where you want me to add the print statement.

Comment: @SG, in def saveFile {}, but that assumes that properties text field is actually getting populated with data post loadFile(). I know groovy far better than I know grails -- hang tight, this is pretty low hanging fruit for a full-time grails user

Comment: et voila, grails user @jjczopek to the rescue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your text field in form tag. This way, when you submit it, you can access your field in controller.

```
<g:form controller="myController" action="saveFile">
  <g:textField name="properties"/>
  <g:submitButton name="saveFile" value="Save File" />
</g:form>
```

Then, you can access your `properties` field in controller:

```
def saveFile = {
    def properties = params.properties
    // do whatever you need
}
```

### EDIT:

To address some of the issues that came up later in comments, I'll try to provide some more insight.

Let's assume that your controller is called `Drive` and view (the form to submit properties) is `drive/properties.gsp`. If want your load button to load your properties into the text area, you can do something like this:

```
def loadFile = {
   // your code here

   render(view: 'properties.gsp', model=[properties:propList])
}
```

And in your view:

```
<g:form controller="drive">
  <g:textArea name="properties" value="${properties?.join("\n")}" rows="50" cols="6"/>
  <br/>
  <g:actionSubmit name="loadFile" action="loadFile" value="Load File"/>
  <g:actionSubmit name="saveFile" action="saveFile" value="Save File"/>
</g:form>
```

This should render your form with values from your file, each property in new line. But I didn't test it.

Comment: this works great for saving the contents of the `textArea` now I'm just having issues loading it from the file.

Comment: thank you for the example! I have edited the main question with an added question, please check it out if you have the chance

Comment: I appreciate the code, I think the problem however deals with the `actionSubmit` both of the buttons can't seem to find the action even when I add the action attribute as you have done. The resulting link when pressing the buttons are like so: `drive/list?loadFile` and `drive/list?saveFile` I'm not sure why it looks for `list` any ideas as to what may be happening?

Comment: It seems to be defaulting `list` as the action. Is there a way to include both actions? I think this is where my issue is occuring

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, for now I'm not placing the load button in a different location

Answer (score 4):

[jjczopek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271787/grails-communicating-between-controllers-and-views/6272006#6272006) shows how to get access to the data in the controller after it has been submitted from the view.

You can pass a default value through from the controller to the view by setting a parameter in the controller eg...

```
    params.param1 ='value to pass'
    render(view:"testView")
```

Then in your view you can retrieve it again with...

```
<g:textField name="text1" value="${params.param1}"/>
```

You may also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985839/request-variables-in-grails) and [these docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/params.html) useful.

If want to pass domain objects through then one of the following specific render methods might be better...
[Grails Controller - Render](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Controllers/render.html)

Comment: @Chris apologies, I have a `textArea` not a `textField`. How would I populate the `textArea`? I seem to be having issues with loading the values into it by iterating the list and assigning the values to the param in my controller

Comment: @Chris I went ahead and just grabbed the text from the file using `getText()` rather than going through it line by line. I have another question which I have edited the original, please check it out if you have the chance. Also thank you for the help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: @StartingGroovy, the g:submitButton should have an 'action' paramater that specifies which action in the controller to use http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html. eg action="loadFile" It defaults to the 'value' paramter but you now have a space in that which is why I assume it's not working.

Comment: @Chris, so have you tried adding action="loadFile"? If you add the action param to g:submitButton then the value param will only be used to display button text

Comment: I modified my answer, maybe some things will clear out. I didn't test this code so it might not work as it it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Chris interesting, when looking at the `submitButton` on grails.org it didn't show the `action` attribute. However, when adding it, it still seems to be looking in the wrong place. When clicking either `submitButton` it can't find the action. Ie: `drive/list?loadFile` and `drive/list?saveFile`

Comment: @Chris I think the reason is that in my `g:form` I don't specify an action (mainly because I have two actions that want to use the form rather than just one) so then it defaults to `list` as the action for the form

Comment: Thank you for your time, for now I'm not placing the load button in a different location